# uninitialized local variable with c++11 default

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined-behavior, default-constructor

Why does printing `b.k` give a warning when printing `a.k` does not? I Use VS2013

```
//warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'b' used
#include<iostream> 

using namespace std;

struct A {
  A() {};
  int k;
};
struct B {
  B() = default;
  int k;
};

int main() {
  A a;
  cout << a.k << endl;
  B b;
  cout << b.k << endl; // this gives a warning, uninitialized local variable

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: funny, gcc warns for a.k but not for b.k

Comment: btw, please add `#include<iostreams>` and `using namespace std;` to your program so that people can copy-paste *working* code

Comment: @TemplateRex added those

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Accessing uninitialized variables is **undefined behavior** and no diagnostic is required. This means that you can get a warning for `b.k` (MSVC++), for `a.k` (g++) or for neither (Clang).

Standard quotes:

**12.6.2 Initializing bases and members [class.base.init]**

> 8 In a non-delegating constructor, if a given non-static data member
>   or base class is not designated by a mem-initializer-id (including the
>   case where there is no mem-initializer-list because the constructor
>   has no ctor-initializer) and the entity is not a virtual base class of
>   an abstract class (10.4), then
>
> [bunch of non-applicable clauses]
>
> — otherwise, the entity is default-initialized (8.5).

**8.5 Initializers [dcl.init]**

> 7 To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> [bunch of non-applicable clauses]
>
> **— otherwise, no initialization is performed.**

The 12.6.2/8 quote has this example:

```
struct C {
    C() { }    // initializes members as follows:
    A a;         // OK: calls A::A()
    const B b;   // error: B has no default constructor
    int i;       // OK: i has indeterminate value // <---------- your code
    int j = 5;   // OK: j has the value 5
};
```

Comment: @Merni yes, the `k` data members of both `a` and `b` are unitialized. That in itself is fine, but you have to assign a value to `k` before you can access it.

Comment: Yes I know, but why does the compiler complain about b and k

Comment: @Merni I guess you could call that warning slightly misleading. Technically, `b` itself indeed is not completely initialized, but it's accessing the unitialized part `k` that is the error

Comment: @TemplateRex That's bull, they are default-initialized, just as billz wrote. Accessing them is perfectly legit.

Comment: @user1095108 well in this case, it's default-initialized with an indeterminate value, and accessing it is undefined behavior. Will change the wording, thanks.

Comment: I have seen no proof for this rumor that using an indeterminate value is undefined behavior. Care to provide a citation? There is a difference between indeterminate value and undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

As per **§ 8.5 Initializers**

`if T has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is default-initialized;`

Which means both `a.k and b.k` are not value initialized, access them are `UB`

To initialize `A::k`, you could put it in member initialize list

```
A():k(42) {};
```

For `B::K`, you could call it with:

```
B b = {}; // value initialize  members, k initialized to 0
```

Comment: A popular misconception among non-programmers is that initializing every variable is a **MUST**, but it is not.